# Expand the content to full parent width

Tags: html, css

I would like to expand the child-content to the full width. I've tried everything and I don't know what can run.
I've only made it run with min-width: n px; but I wouldn't like to define a specific width in pixels because the design won't be adaptive in smaller screens.

https://jsfiddle.net/tiranium/e8w22j39/

HTML

```
<div class="ficha_container">
  <div class="ficha_row">
    <div class="ficha_cell">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>Content.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.ficha_container {
  display: table;
  background-color: green;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}
.ficha_row {
  display: table-row;
}
.ficha_cell {
  display: table-cell;
}
.ficha_cell p {
  background: pink;
}
```

Comment: why do you use `display:table-row;` and `display: table-cell;` ? without that the child divs will be of full width.

Comment: do you mean you want content to extend outside the row of table? Coz its already at the full width of its parent,ie.,ficha_cell

Comment: Why are you setting the display twice on .ficha_container? If you just use display: table; and add width:100% it seems to give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want a `display:table` solution, you can't also add `display: block` to the same element.

My guess why you did that, were to make it full width.

To make a `table` full width you simply set it to 100%, so to make your existing markup work properly, remove `display: block` from `.ficha_container` and add `width: 100%;`

```css
.ficha_container{
  display:table;  
  background-color: green;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}
.ficha_row{
  display:table-row;
}
.ficha_cell{
  display: table-cell;
}
.ficha_cell p{
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="ficha_container">
  <div class="ficha_row">
    <div class="ficha_cell">
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p>Content.</p> 


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```